# Qual a origem da expressão "pagar mico"?

Tags: etimologia, expressões, português-brasileiro, expressões-idiomáticas, origem

Diz-se “pagar o mico” quando se refere a passar por uma situação constrangedora, cometer gafe. "Pagar" também pode significar “agir como".

Então, pelo que posso presumir, uma pessoa pagar mico seria como se ela agisse como um mico, e assim quem vê pode achar “engraçado” e quem passa por isso se constrange com a situação? Seria isso? A origem seria apenas conceitual ou houve um acontecimento histórico que deu origem a essa expressão?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Pagar mico*** tem origem no jogo de cartas infantil conhecido por ***mico*** ou ***mico-preto***. (*Mico* é também a designação de várias espécies de macacos.) Veja-se no [Aulete digital:](http://www.aulete.com.br/mico)

> mico2 (mi.co)
>   **1.** Lud. O mesmo que mico-preto2.
>   **2.** Bras. Gír. Situação que envergonha; VEXAME
>   [F.: Red[ução] de mico-preto2, ligada à ideia da situação embaraçosa de quem fica com a carta do mico-preto no jogo.]

No jogo do mico os jogadores formam pares de cartas. Há uma carta que não tem par, a *carta do mico*. O jogo para quando a um jogador restar apenas a *carta do mico*. Este jogador é excluído, e dos restantes ganha aquele que tiver feito mais pares. Ficar com o mico é portanto embaraçoso. Este jogo pode ser jogado com um ou dois baralhos de cartas normais, tal como descrito [neste site](http://jogosdecartas.hut.com.br/mico/). Nesse caso retira-se uma carta no início do jogo, ficando portanto no baralho uma carta sem par. Há também baralhos especiais para este jogo que incluem uma carta com a figura de um mico preto [(ver *mico-preto* no Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/mico-preto).

Comment: Ah, não fazia ideia que vinha de um jogo, ótima resposta, 1+!  Sobre o "agir como", é que aqui pelo Brasil "pagar de" também pode significar o mesmo que "dar uma de", "agir como", como em "pagar de playboy", "pagar de rico", etc. Por isso supus que talvez fosse algo relacionado com isso.

Comment: @BrunoLopes Eu baseei-me inteiramente no Aulete. Achei a entrada deles muito convincente. Não conhecia esse significado de *pagar de*. Não vem ainda nos dicionários online. Deve ser recente, não?

Comment: Acho que sim, não sei exatamente quando começou a ser usado, mas é mais ou menos recente. É uma gíria, nada muito oficial.